# Flutter PageRoute didComplete override not completing if the Controller was modified

Tags: flutter, animation, routes, overriding

I have overridden didComplete() from PageRoute in Flutter.

For some reason, controlling the animation controller stops the route from completing. The animation is handles as expected, no error is thrown however a modal route is still blocking the screen below even though it is not visible.

```
@override
  void didComplete(T? result) {
    super
        .controller
        ?.animateTo(
          0,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          duration: reverseTransitionDuration,
        )
        .then((value) {});
    super.didComplete(result);
  }
```

I have tried adding various dispose methods but it seems the route and the controller are correctly disposed.

If I remove the animation of the controller then didComplete works as expected.

```
 @override
  void didComplete(T? result) {
    super.didComplete(result);
  }
```

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is present any time the scroll controller is modified. Essentially the route does not finalise even though it does pop because not all of its resources are complete. In this case that resource is the AnimationController.

The solution therefore is to finalise the route once the modification to the controller is complete:

```
Navigator.of(context).finaliseRoute(this);
```

If performing this action in a widget inside a route then this can be achieved by accessing the ModalRoute inherited Widget as well as the Navigator:

```
ModalRoute? route = ModalRoute.of(context);

Navigator.of(context).finalizeRoute(route);
```

Comment: Don't modify the Route controller. It is protected for a reason. Modyfying it will do all manner of unpredictable behaviour to Overlay entries and NavigatorState.